# How to view user response to Motion & Fitness Activity UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-motion

I am working on an app that requires access to a user's Motion & Fitness activity -- namely the pedometer data. In the onboarding of this app I have a button that calls the `startUpdates` method of my CMPedometer object, which triggers iOS to display a UIAlertViewController asking the user to decide if this app has permission to access that data or not.

Code for button:

```
func didSelectActionButton() {
        switch state {
        case .appFirstLaunched:
            pedometer.startUpdates(from: Date()) { (pedometerData, error) in
            }
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(checkPermissionsEverySecond), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        case .noPermissionGranted:
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(checkPermissionsEverySecond), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        case .permissionGranted:
            pedometer = nil     navigationController?.pushViewController(RecordMeasurementController(), animated: true)

        }
    }

func checkPermissionsEverySecond() {
        if timerInSeconds < 5  && CMSensorRecorder.isAuthorizedForRecording() {
            permissionGranted()
            timer.invalidate()
        } else {
            noPermissionGranted())
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        timerInSeconds += 1
    }
```

As the code above describes, there are three states: 1) appFirstLaunched, 2) noPermissionGranted, 3) permissionGranted. My detection of whether the user allows access to the data and the subsequent state change feels sloppy. Ideally I would like my app to respond immediately to what the user selects in the UIAlertViewController.

Is it possible to get a more immediate indication of what the user selected instead of checking `CMSensorRecorder.isAuthorizedForRecording()` every n seconds?